# material-table overriding pagination component causing warnings

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

`enter code here`I am trying to override the pagination component in material-table. The functionality thatI added is working perfectly - however i get warnings in the console.The warning is given below.

> Material-UI: The key `selectRoot` provided to the classes prop is not
> implemented in MTablePaginationInner. You can only override one of the
> following: root.
>
> Material-UI: The key `caption` provided to the classes prop is not
> implemented in MTablePaginationInner. You can only override one of the
> following: root

here is the code fragment of the material-ui table

```
        <MaterialTable 
            columns={columns} 
            data={invoices} 
            icons={IconsForMaterialTable}
            options={{ paging:true}}
            components={{
                Pagination: (subProps) => {
                    return <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end"> <Box width="260px" justifyContent="flex-end">
                        <MTablePagination {...subProps} count={pageCount} onChangePage={(e, page) => setPage(page)} page={page} rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}/>
                    </Box></Box>
                }}}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings you see are telling you that you are passing a prop named `classes` to [MTablePagination](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-pagination.js) component, and the `classes` object looks like below, for example:

```
const classes = {
  root: "some_class_name",
  selectRoot: "another_class_name",
  caption: "one_more_class_name"
}
```

But [MTablePagination](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-pagination.js) is **not** using few classes properties like `selectRoot` and `caption`, but using only `root` property (it can be seen in the [source-code](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/42d966eacdbe47cd176f9c5c68e3d97b126b489e/src/components/m-table-pagination.js#L45)).

Hence, you can safely **ignore** these warnings or write something like this to remove it:

```
components={{
  Pagination: (subProps) => {
      return <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end"> <Box width="260px" justifyContent="flex-end">
          <MTablePagination {...subProps} classes={{root: subProps.classes.root}} /* Rest of the code, removed for brevity.*/ />
      </Box></Box>
  }}}
                                           ^^^^ Passing classes
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks a ton. A superb explanation